# Slim Framework: Insert query issue

Tags: php, slim

I am new to the [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/). I don't know how to perform an insert query in Slim framework.

Please can somebody show me an example or tutorial to understand it better.
I have read the Android hive tutorial but am still not clear.

I am not able to post the params when using advanced REST API.

0 Response is generated.

Below is my code for `index.php` file:

```
global $name;

$app->get('/saveEvent', function() {
    global $user_id;
    $response = array();
    $db = new DbHandler();
    $name = $app->request->post('name');
    $result = $db->createUser($name);

    //$response["error"] = false;
    if ($result != NULL) {
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "Task created successfully";
    } else {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Failed to create task. Please try again";
    }
    echoRespnse(201, $response);
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: You're using a `get` route, but then you're trying to retrieve `POST`ed parameters?

Comment: when i use a post route , it gives 404 response error

Comment: Advance rest api response is 404 when i pass params

Comment: What do you mean by "advance"?  Please update your question to show your code with the `post` route.

Comment: Using `globals` is strongly discouraged. It's like using dynamite to power your car.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of how you would perform a post:

```
$app->post("/book", function () use($app, $db) {
    $app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    $book = $app->request()->post();
    $result = $db->books->insert($book);
    echo json_encode(array("id" => $result["id"]));
});
```